# POST doesn't happen in ajax

Tags: python, django, jquery

I have a simple form to submit and test ajax,but it doesn't work and I see any problem in it,I searched alot and there was no more poin-at least I dedn't see ;)

in `urls.py`

```
(r'^doctors/shahsavand/visiting/$','DrHub.views.visiting'),
(r'^doctors/shahsavand/visiting/add/$','DrHub.views.ajxTest')
```

the first URL is to direct to main page and there's this form in main page:

```
<form method='POST' action=".">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <ul>
            <li>
                <label for="start">Start Time: </label><input name="id_startTime" id="id_startTime" type="text" />          
            </li>
            <li>
                <label for="end">End Time: </label><input name="id_endTime" id="id_endTime" type="text" />
            </li>
        </ul>
        <input type="submit" id="save_button" name="save_button" value="add" />
</form>
```

and ajax code in this page:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='/static/DrHub/doctors/shahsavand/js/jquery-1.4.1.js'></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $.ajax({
                 type:"POST",
                 url:"{% url DrHub.views.ajxTest %}",
                 data: {
                        'start': $('#id_startTime').val(),
                        'end': $('#id_endTime').val(),
                        'csrfmiddlewaretoken':$( "#csrfmiddlewaretoken" ).val()
                 },
                 success: function(data){
                     alert(data);
                 }
    });
</script>
```

in `views.py` :

```
def ajxTest(request):
    if request.is_ajax():
          if request.method == 'POST':
             return HttpResponse(simplejson.dumps({'message' : 'awesome'}),  mimetype='application/javascript')
    else:
          return render_to_response('DrHub/doctors/nutrition/test.html', context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

I did this to test if `ajxTest view` is called:

```
def ajxTest(request):
   if request.is_ajax():
      raise Http404
   else:
      pass
```

and this :

```
def ajxTest(request):
       if request.is_ajax():
          raise pass
       else:
          Http404
```

but no result and that sounds like my ajax POST is not associated with `ajxTest view` !!!

```
edit
```

when I check firebug I get `403 forbidden error` that is for `CSRF` and I've tryed many things to solve it again no result :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the javascript described in [the documentation for csrf](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/csrf/#ajax) and it should fix your problem.

Comment: where should I put this code?should I put it in a js file and refrence to it?or paste it in main page,right before my ajax code?when I paste it before my ajax code Forbidden error convert to INTERNAL SERVER ERROR!

Comment: Just reference it in your head from an external file.

Comment: when I reference to it in a separate .js file,I have the same INTERNAL SERVER ERROR!!!

Comment: remove `'csrfmiddlewaretoken':$( "#csrfmiddlewaretoken" ).val()`, turn on debugging and post a stack trace if you are still having problems.

Comment: ya,yaa , It's OK ,now my problem is that POST data is undefiend,I use this in view simplejson.dumps({'message' : request.POST.get('start')}) and U can see how I sent start to view.